# Reflecting the trace of a polynomial about a vertical line

Tags: plotting, geometry, homework

[image]

I am doing this question and up to $b$ and $c$ and I am wondering how I can reflect the graph, I managed to do part $a$. I know the equation for part $b$ is `y == (x - 22)^3 + 8` because I did it by hand, but I am not sure how I would plot to graphs on the same graph for question $c$

Comment: `Plot` can plot multiple equations at once. Try for instance: `Plot[{(x - 2)^3 - 8, (22 - x)^3 + 8}, {x, 0, 24}, PlotRange -> {0, 72}]`. Since you seem to know the necessary coordinate transformation, look into using a replacement rule on the original equation (see `ReplaceAll`). For instance, consider what happens to your original equation under the transformation rule: `x -> (24 - x)`.

Comment: Hint: `y == (x - 22)^3 + 8` is not the correct answer for *b*